# Svelte can't find name of Vite variable

Tags: svelte, vite

I have a Svelte app using Vite and I need the current app version during runtime.

In the *vite.config.ts* I added a global variable

```
  define: {
    APP_VERSION: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version),
  },
```

Inside my component I use the variable like so

```
<script lang="ts">
const appVersion = APP_VERSION;

function doSomething() {
    console.log(appVersion);
}
</script>
```

which works but when running `npm run check` I get the error

> Error: Cannot find name 'APP_VERSION'. Did you mean 'appVersion'? (ts)

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a declaration, e.g. add a file `vite.d.ts` with the content:

```js
declare const APP_VERSION: string;
```

(Note that if you add imports to the file, the file would become a module and the declaration will no longer be considered global. You then would have to wrap the declaration in a `declare global { ... }` block.)

If you use the variable directly in the template part of a Svelte file you will currently still get a warning which can be silenced using:

```html
<!-- svelte-ignore missing-declaration -->
```